# Expandable tableView cell visible issue for bottom row?

Tags: swift, uitableview, expandablelistview

I have the tableview cell with expandable row its working fine. Now I have the issues on when bottom cell of the table view row it will expand but user need move to tableview for viewing expandable part. how to do it will move automatically?

Comment: Hey ben can you add your code and image of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Let's_Create I update my questions with image

Comment: try tblVw.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: (sender.view?.tag)!, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are reloading the section after expand/collapse the 'tableView' sections.
You can scroll the tableView to the section rect you are expanding.

**For ex:**

```
let sectionRect = tableView.rect(forSection: section)
tableView.scrollRectToVisible(sectionRect, animated: false)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to achive for row

Comment: tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath)

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async { tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)  its working like charms

Answer (score 0):

Better use the `func scrollRectToVisible(_ rect: CGRect, animated: Bool)` this method does not scroll the tableview if the section is visible. You can easy to get the section rect using this method `func rect(forSection section: Int) -> CGRect`

example:

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates({ [weak tableView] in
        tableView?.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
 }, completion: { [weak tableView] _ in
        if let sectionRect = tableView?.rect(forSection: section) {
             tableView.scrollRectToVisible(sectionRect, animated: true) 
        }
 })
```